# How to add new Key to nested plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have Custom plist in my app, I want to add new key at nested level.

How can i add it ? programatically ?

Here is the structure of my plist file:
[image]:
How to achieve this ?

**Please help and thanks in advance.**

Comment: Press that `+` button?

Comment: What's the problem at the moment? Why can't you add it? Do you want to edit the file as @trojanfoe mentioned, or do you want to do it programmatically throughout your code?

Comment: I want to add it programtically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not edit files in you App-Bundle. You will have to read it in as a `NSMutableDictionary`, change it and save it to your Documents Folder.

```
/*--- get bundle file      ---*/
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Products" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *rootDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

/*--- set value with key   ---*/
[rootDict setValue:@"NewKeyContent" forKeyPath:@"Mobiles.Brands.TheNewKey"];

/*--- get documents path   ---*/
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Products.plist"];

/*--- save file            ---*/
[rootDict writeToFile:writablePath atomically: YES];
```

After that you will have to open it from the Documents directory otherwise you will always start with clean slate.

```
/*--- get documents file   ---*/
NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *path = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Products.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *rootDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

/*--- set value with key   ---*/
[rootDict setValue:@"NewKeyContent" forKeyPath:@"Mobiles.Brands.TheNewKey"];

/*--- get bundle file      ---*/
[rootDict writeToFile:writablePath atomically: YES];
```

Comment: When i wrote this `Mobiles.Brands.TheNewKey` key added under Mobiles and not under Mobiles.Brands

Comment: I'm sorry. Its `setValue:forKeyPath:`. I fixed the anser code.

Comment: Superb it works dude, but what if i want to check whether that key exists in plist. for that what syntax should i use ?

Comment: `if ([rootDict valueForKeyPath:@"Mobiles.Brands.TheNewKey"]){NSLog(@"exists");} else {NSLog(@"missing");};`

Comment: Thanks, but you might wanna crop that image and fix the bottom text.

Comment: Dude do u know, if i want to remove existed key in plist. for that what syntax should i use ?

Comment: Use removeObjectForKey method

Comment: it doesn't work, i have tried :( it may be bcoz i have added value using `setvalue` so for removing should be a method called `removevalueforkey` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use NSMutableDictionary + (id /* NSDictionary * */)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path to create a dictionary. And use 
[dictionary setValue:@"new_value" forKeyPath:@"Mobiles.Brands.new_key"];

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you should just add the new key in the plist editor by clicking the "+" button.

If you want to edit your plist in code it's much more complicated.

plist files are read into memory with all their objects immutable. You need to create a mutable copy of the entire branch down to the object you want to add. Something like this:

```
//Make a mutable copy of the outermost dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *outer = [startingOuterDict mutableCopy];

//Create a mutable copy of the dictionary at key "Mobiles" and replace it in "outer"
NSMutableDictionary *mobiles =  [outer[@"Mobiles"] mutableCopy];
outer[@"Mobiles"] = mobiles;

//Create a mutable copy of the dictionary at key "Brands" and replace it in "mobiles"
NSMutableDictionary *brands =  [mobiles[@"Brands"] mutableCopy];
mobiles[@"Brands"] = brands;

//Finally, add a new key in the "Brands" dictionary
brands[@"newKey"] = @"Apple";
```

It is possible, though tricky, to write a "mutableDeepCopy" method that converts all the containers in an object graph of dictionaries, arrays, and sets, to their mutable equivalents. You don't need that in this case however.